# How to define a Fortran type equivalent object in Julia

Tags: julia

I have a Fortran type I defined as mean_covar like below,

```
type :: mean_covar
    real(kind=r8), allocatable :: mu(:,:)
    real(kind=r8), allocatable :: sigma(:,:)
    real(kind=r8) :: w
end type
```

So that I can set some variable as type Mean_covar.

I want to define the same thing in Julia, I know Julia has something called struct, with mutable property its fields can be changed. So I did a very simply thing like,

```
mutable struct Mean_covar
    mu::Array{Float64,2}
end
```

Then I define,

```
musigma = Mean_covar(Array{Float64,2}(undef,2,2))
```

so I can then set musigma.mu as any 2d array I want.

But I just wonder, does it has to be so cumbersome when defining musigma (need to set the value of each fields)? Can I just simply do

```
musigma::Mean_covar
```

But this give me an error,

```
UndefVarError: musigma not defined
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly sure how you want to structure your data but you could do:

```
struct MeanCovar
    mu::Matrix{Float64}
    MeanCovar(n) = new(zeros(n,n))
end
```

This could be used as simple as:

```
julia> m = MeanCovar(2)
MeanCovar([0.0 0.0; 0.0 0.0])
```

Note that when you know the size of MeanCovar it can be not mutable since you can still mutate the values in `mu`, as `mu` hold only reference to the array.

```
julia> m.mu[1,1] = 66
66

julia> m.mu
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 66.0  0.0
  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, could you please explain a little bit more about when to use mutable, and when to use immutable?

Comment: It's more of an art than a science. Basically, for objects that you want to feel like numbers, you probably want immutable. If you are making something more like a collection, you typically want mutability.

Comment: Basically for small objects (`struct`s) it is faster to dump an immutable object and recreate it than mutate a mutable one - the immutable objects are differently aligned in memory and the access is much faster. If you use "dump me whenever you mutate" pattern programming is slightly less convenient but there are Julia packages supporting this pattern via a set of macros.